# Nested replies almost done, only need to arrange them in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm currently doing a small forum in Laravel. This will include(ofcourse) commenting on posts. I also done replies on top of comments. I've done this by adding post_id, commenter_id and parent_id field in Comment model. And that's all alright.And i also done small margin that each reply have depending on their parent .What i have trouble with is displaying appropriate reply, for example: Comment1, then reply to comm.1, then another reply to that reply and so on, then another direct reply on Comment1, every subsequent reply to reply after second direct comment on Comment1 isn't grouped with other replies. How to achieve that?

Here is image of what i'm trying to achieve:
[image: show view with post and it's comments/replies]

Here is Comment model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'parent_id',
        'body'
    ];

    public function commentPost(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Post","post_id");
    }

    public function commentAuthor(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User","commenter_id");
    }

    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Here is show view:

```
@extends("layouts.app")

@section("content")
    <?php 
        /*Pregleda zasebno za title i description da li ima gresaka. 
        Ukoliko ih ima, dodeljume im klasu(crveni border).*/
        $errBody = $errors->has('body') ? 'shake' : '';
    ?>
    <a href="/posts" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Go Back</a>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <a href="/posts/{{$prev}}" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <a href="/posts/{{$next}}" class="btn btn-outline-info"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1> 
    <div class="postContainer">
        <img class="postCover" src="/storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}">

            <div>
            <!--Ovako prikazuje html kod.-->
            <!--{{$post->body}}-->
                {!!$post->body!!}
            </div>

            <small class="timestamp">Written on {{$post->created_at}}</small>
    </div>

    @if(!Auth::guest())
        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)
            <hr>
            <a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>

            <form action="/posts/{{$post->id}}" method="post" class="float-right">
                @csrf
                {{method_field("DELETE")}}

                <!-- The Modal -->
                <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">

                        <!-- Modal Header -->
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Are yoy sure you want to delete this post?</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal body -->
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
        @endif
    @endif

    @auth
    <hr>

    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)
        <form method="POST" action="/posts/{{$post->id}}/comments">
            @csrf
            <!-- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules -->

            <div class="form-group animated {{$errBody}}">
                <textarea id="ckeditor" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Post body" required value=""></textarea>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">Post comment</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    @endif

    <hr>
    @endauth
    <h6 style="border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;">Comments <span class="badge" style="background-color: whitesmoke; border: 1px solid silver;vertical-align: top;">{{count($comments)}}</span></h6>
    <div class="container commContainer">

        <ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type:none">
            @if(count($comments) > 0)
                @foreach ($comments as $index => $comment)

                    <li>

                        @if($index>0)
                            <div class="horDiv"></div>
                        @endif

                        {{$comment->commentAuthor->name}} has said parent_id: {{$comment->parent_id}}
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{$comment->parent_id}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$comment->parent_id}}" id="{{$comment->id}}">My id: {{$comment->id}} {!!$comment->body!!} 
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)
                            <br><span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="width: 40px;height: 20px;line-height: 5px;padding: 5px;" onclick="reply('reply{{ $comment->id }}')";>reply</span>
                            @include('inc.replyForm')
                        @endif
                    </li>

                @endforeach

            @endif

        </ul>

    </div>

@endsection
```

I'm just guessing, but can it be done by in view itself?I tried grouping and ordering before controller passes it to view, but nothing had desired effect. I appreciate every point in right direction.

**Edit:**
Here is store method in CommentsController.

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            "body" => "required"

        ]);

        $data = array(
            "body" => $request->input("body"),
            "post_id" => intval($id),
            "commenter_id" => Auth::user()->id,
            "imParent_id" => $request->input("comment_id")
        );
        //dd($data);
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->body = $data["body"];
        $comment->post_id = $data["post_id"];
        $comment->commenter_id = $data["commenter_id"];
        $comment->parent_id = $data["imParent_id"];

        $comment->save();

        $post = Post::find($id);
        $comments = $post->comments;
        //return redirect("/posts/{{$id}}")->with("success", "Post Created")->with('comments', $comments);
        //return view("posts.show")->with(compact('post', 'comments'));
        //with(['replies' => function($comments){ $comments->orderBy('parent_id') } ])
        return back()->with('comments', $comments);
    }
```

**Edit2:**

And here is show method in PostController:

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $post = Post::find($id);  

        $comments = $post->comments;

        $prev = $post->prev($post);
        $next = $post->next($post);

        return view("posts.show")->with(compact("post", "prev", "next", "comments"));
    }
```

**Edit3:**

Here is rather flawed attempt(in show view):

```
@if(count($comments) > 0)

                @for($i=0;$i<count($comments);$i++)

                    @if(!$comments[$i]->parent_id)
                        <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" parent_id="{{$comments[$i]->parent_id}}" id="{{$comments[$i]->id}}">
                            {!!$comments[$i]->body!!}
                        </li>
                        @for($k=0;$k<count($comments);$k++)

                            @if($comments[$i]->id==$comments[$k]->parent_id)
                            <?php array_push($myArray,$comments[$i]->id); ?>
                                <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{$comments[$k]->parent_id}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$comments[$k]->parent_id}}" id="{{$comments[$k]->id}}">
                                    {!!$comments[$k]->body!!}
                                </li>
                            @endif

                        @endfor
                        {{"///////////////////////////////////////////////"}}
                    @endif

                    @if(array_search($comments[$i]->parent_id,$myArray)===false)


                        @for($k=0;$k<count($comments);$k++)

                            @if($comments[$i]->id==$comments[$k]->parent_id)


                            <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{$comments[$k]->parent_id}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$comments[$k]->parent_id}}" id="{{$comments[$k]->id}}">
                                {!!$comments[$k]->body!!}
                            </li>

                            @endif

                        @endfor

                    @endif

                @endfor
@endif
```

And how it looks along with duplicates:

[image: duplicates]

Edit4:

Followed Tim Lewis advice of separating comments(parentless) from replies(with parents), here's how to displayed them and sending additional parameter to reply form partial:

```
<ul class="list-group" style="list-style-type:none">
            @if(count($comms) > 0)

                @for($i=0;$i<count($comms);$i++)

                    <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{"0"}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$comms[$i]->parent_id}}" id="{{$comms[$i]->id}}">

                        {{$comms[$i]->body}}

                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)

                            <br><span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="width: 40px;height: 20px;line-height: 5px;padding: 5px;" onclick="reply('reply{{ $comms[$i]->id }}')";>reply</span>
                            @include('inc.replyForm', array('par' => $comms[$i]))

                        @endif

                    </li>

                    <li>@if($i>0) <div class="horDiv"></div> @endif </li>

                    @if(count($replies) > 0)

                        @for($j=0;$j<count($replies);$j++)

                            @if($comms[$i]->id==$replies[$j]->parent_id)
                                <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{$comms[$i]->id}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$replies[$j]->parent_id}}" id="{{$replies[$j]->id}}">

                                    {{$replies[$j]->body}}

                                    @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)

                                        <br><span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="width: 40px;height: 20px;line-height: 5px;padding: 5px;" onclick="reply('reply{{ $replies[$j]->id }}')";>reply</span>
                                        @include('inc.replyForm', array('par' => $replies[$j]))

                                    @endif

                                </li>
                                <li>@if($j>0) <div class="horDiv"></div> @endif </li>
                            @endif

                            @for($k=$j;$k<count($replies);$k++)

                                @if($replies[$k]->parent_id==$replies[$j]->id)
                                    <li class="list-group-item py-2 commBody" style="margin-left: calc({{$replies[$j]->id}}*10px) !important" parent_id="{{$replies[$k]->parent_id}}" id="{{$replies[$k]->id}}">

                                        {{$replies[$k]->body}}

                                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role_id<3 && Auth::user()->role_id>0)

                                            <br><span class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" style="width: 40px;height: 20px;line-height: 5px;padding: 5px;" onclick="reply('reply{{ $replies[$k]->id }}')";>reply</span>
                                            @include('inc.replyForm', array('par' => $replies[$k]))

                                        @endif

                                    </li>
                                    <li>@if($k>0) <div class="horDiv"></div> @endif </li>
                                @endif

                            @endfor

                        @endfor

                    @endif

                @endfor

            @endif
        </ul>
```

Comment: try with(['replies' => function($query){ $query->orderBy('parent_id')  } ]) ?

Comment: @Ahmed Aboud Not sure where to put this. Here is edit with store method.

Comment: You're going to need recursion to handle this. Indenting by `{X}px` isn't enough. What does your query for `$comments` look like? Essentially, you'd query for "top level comments", which are those that don't have a parent, then loop over them, then their children, then children of children, etc etc. It's complicated, and maybe a bit too broad in it's current state.

Comment: @Tim Lewis Well, yeah ... That's why i'm asking for help. Maybe someone sees something in all of this that i currently don't. I'm doing something like that in view and it's 70% successful i.e. 2 of 7 comments(including replies) are double printing, so instead original 7 comments there are 9 including duplicates.

Comment: I know, and there's nothing wrong with asking for help; sorry if that comment seems that way. All I'm saying is it's going to be difficult to get a response on Stackoverflow for something this broad. At a glance, I don't see any recursion, and I believe that is necessary to accomplish what you're trying to do. I've done infinite-level nesting like this (where a model references itself, as a parent-child relationship), and it's complicated. Back to my original comment, what does your initial query look like? Are you only searching for those that have a `parent_id` of 0?

Comment: @Tim Lewis Grab all comments associated with given post. Ordinary relation in Post model: public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Comment"); and in Comment model: public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'parent_id');
    }
    }

Comment: I can't help if you don't post the code for the **query**, not the relationship. But, I'm sensing that it isn't something like `$comments = $post->comments()->where("parent_id", "=", 0)->with(["replies"])->get();`, so you'd be getting all comments and replies. That explains why, when looping `$comment->replies`, you get duplicates; the same comment is going to be in `$comments` and `$comment->replies`.

Comment: @Tim Lewis So you're suggesting that collect(independently) comments and replies and then, in view, properly display them.

Comment: Yes, since replies branch off of comments, you can (and currently are) getting them when you loop over each comment. If you omit them from the original query, you'll ensure you don't have duplicates. But of course, you have to loop `$comments->replies`, then `$reply->replies`, etc. recursively.

Comment: $post = Post::with(['replies' => function($query){ $query->orderBy('parent_id') } ])->find($id);   take a look at eager loading

Comment: @Tim Lewis I think i done it. It displays it nicely, with indentation and all. Take look at edit4.

Answer (score 0):

I did it before for making categories. Here is a tip:

```
<select name="category_id" class="form-control chosen-select" required value="{{ old('category_id') }}">
            @foreach(App\Category::where('parent_id',0)->get() as $c)
                <option value="{{$c->id}}">*{{$c->name}}</option>
                @foreach(App\Category::where('parent_id',$c->id)->get() as $d1)
                    <option value="{{$d1->id}}"> - {{$d1->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endforeach
        </select>
```